# I'm working on d3.js. Why this code doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

That's the CSV file: http://goo.gl/ZVVjD

I've this problem only for bar chart. The line chart works fine. I don't know how to modify this one.

Please,help me to understand where I'm wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//var formatPercent = d3.format("04d");
//var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y-%H:%M:%S").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
//.tickFormat(formatPercent);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        //d.energy = parseInt(d.energy);
        d.energy = +d.energy;
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.energy; })]);
    //y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.energy; }));

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Energy");

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.energy); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.energy); });
});

</script>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, It views the axis correctly but not the bars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe `x.rangeBand()` works for time scales. Try replacing it with with a fixed pixel value of 2 or 3.

Comment: :) Thank you! That's the problem! This was my first question on Stackoverflow. Thank you very much.